# wixtoolset 4: how to use conditions?

Tags: wix, wix4

I'm trying to create a mso with wixtoolset 4, unfortunately most examples/documentation is for wixtoolset 3 and I'm currently unable to succesfully add a condition.

I have installed the [bal extension nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WixToolset.Bal.wixext)

**Product.wxs**

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">

    <Package Name="MyPackage" Manufacturer="Koch IT" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="xxxxxxxx-fcae-496b-b7c9-8cfc36fbc157">
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Feature Id="Main">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExampleComponents" />
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="RegistryEntries" />
        </Feature>
    </Package>
</Wix>
```

**Condition.wxs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">

    <Fragment Id="VSTORUNTIMEREDIST_Fragment">
        <Property Id="VSTORUNTIMEREDIST">
            <RegistrySearch
              Id="VSTORuntimeRedist"
              Root="HKLM"
              Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R"
              Name="Version"
              Type="raw" />

        </Property>
        <bal:Condition Condition="Installed OR VSTORUNTIMEREDIST>=20.0.30319"
          Message="The Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime is not installed. 
  Please download and install from 
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479.">
        </bal:Condition>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

So I thought that I can somehow reference the whole fragment but his has been deprecated since long.

I then tried to just add it to my `<Fragment>` in `ExampleComponents.wxs` which is referenced in `Product.wxs` which handles the files to include in the msi,

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">
    <Fragment>
        <PropertyRef Id="VSTORUNTIMEREDIST"></PropertyRef>
        <bal:Condition Condition="Installed OR VSTORUNTIMEREDIST>=20.0.30319"
          Message="The Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime is not installed. 
  Please download and install from 
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479.">
        </bal:Condition>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Guid="xxxxxxxx-f350-4b51-b08a-7bd7f45412df">
                <File Source="MyApp.dll" />
                <File Source="MyApp.vsto" />
                <File Source="MyApp.dll.manifest" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

There are so called  `bundles` but this seems like a real overkill for what I want and I wasn't able to figure out how to put it together.

How can I reference this Condition so it's properly evaluated during install?

*Yes, I know that the condition will always evaluate to `false` that's the point, for testing*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a launch condition, which you can author using the [`Launch` element](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/launch/).